# Redressing the Geologic Face of Japan

Tags: geography, geology

[image]

Back home, the islands of Japan are created by the subduction of three separate plates--Eurasian, Philippine and Pacific.  The result--Japan being the hottest spot for both earthquakes and active volcanoes.  The lowest point is Lake Hachirōgata, down 16 feet below sea level.  The highest point is Mount Fuji, standing 12,388 feet above sea level.  As you can see from this map, coastal plains are plain to see, but volcanic mountain ranges dominate the nation.

This is Japan in an alternate Earth:

[image]

It is formed by seven separate mantle plumes (red circles) cornered on both sides by the Pacific (magenta) and Northern (yellow) plates.  Which makes Japan's volcanoes both subductive and hotspot.

Would this have changed the landscape--let alone the shape--of the Japanese arc in any way?

Comment: I somehow doubt it could happen. Can tectonic work that way?

Comment: Aren't mantle plumes usually in the middle of a large continental plate?

Comment: To clarify, the Northern (yellow and everything to the left of it) is continental, the Pacific (magenta and all to the right) is oceanic? And what's the plate or space between them?

Comment: @Zxyrra  Yes on the first question.  And the space between them is oceanic.

Comment: @ohwilleke the Hawaiian Islands, the Canary Islands and the Azores are all examples of Hotspot related island chains in the middle of oceans, there are others.

Comment: @Sarriesfan This is basically what I meant. None of those hotspots are at the edges of tectonic plates while the ones in hypothetical Japan seem to be more or less between two plates.

Comment: @ohwilleke they are in Oceanic plates rather than Continental Plates, there are hotspots at plate boundaries such as Iceland although They are at MORs not subduction zones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think that instead of ridges you would get a topography similar to the shape of the Jeppesen Terminal at Denver International Airport (photo credit to Denver International Airport) with lots of successive peaks instead of the long ridges such of those of the Rocky Mountains in the background.

[image: Jeppesen Terminal]

Compare a crude schematic (via [Getty Images](http://www.gettyimages.ca/detail/illustration/cross-section-illustration-showing-chain-of-royalty-free-illustration/85594928)) of the Hawaiian islands

[image]

Incidentally, I don't think you'd need seven hot spots, because they tend to migrate. The four southern hotspots could easily be a single migrating hotspot and produce essentially the same topography, and indeed all six could be from a single hot spot if the Japan plate in the hypothetical case was moving rapidly in geological terms early on and was twisted a bit from pressures from the adjacent plates. A formation like that would be more in line with real world precedents.

In terms of weather, this ought to expose western Japan to more intense typhoons.

Subduction zones on both sides of the island would also greatly increase volcano and earthquake activity in western Japan.

A subduction zone to the west of Japan would also greatly change its ecology, because a western Japan trench formed by the subduction zone would have prevented any land bridges or very shallow sea access to the islands as happened historically which was a major source of its pre-Iron Age population (the Jomon) and was also a source of much of its terrestrial life. With subduction zones on each side Japan would have terrestrial fauna and flora that would be much more distinct from the mainland in real world Japan, more like [pre-Maori New Zealand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fauna_of_New_Zealand).

This topography would also probably greatly increase the number of distinct watersheds in the region, eliminating the long rivers necessary for larger freshwater fish.

Comment: Could islands as close to the mainland as Japan have such distinctive wildlife?  New Zealand is a very valid example, except that New Zealand is 4155 kilos from Australia.

Comment: The Korea straight is 200km long and 90 meters deep; there was a land bridge across it in some ice ages. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korea_Strait http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs003670000039 Any land animal that can't build boats needs a land bridge and it doesn't matter if it the straight is 20 km or 2000 km, as long as it is more than the land animal can comfortably swim in reproductive pairs. Coastal fishing boats usually needed to be in sight of land at all times which is about 50km tops at sea, so it would still be long enough and they also don't do well in deep waters.

Answer (score -2):

## Yes.

That part was simple. The question you didn't ask, exactly how Japan would look like, is way too broad.

Comment: I did ask that.

Comment: @JohnWDailey That isn't the question you asked; o.m. is right. If you intended to ask what Japan would like (rather than if it would look different), I would suggest revising your question. Until then, this does answer the question.

Comment: "Would this have changed the landscape--let alone the shape--of the Japanese arc in any way?"  That, word-by-word, was the question.

Comment: @JohnWDailey, the answer to that question is "yes." You probably wanted to ask "How would the landscape be changed?" which I would have marked as *too broad*.

Comment: @o.m.  That is an excuse that never works the first time.

Comment: @JohnWDailey, the question has been **closed**. Are you going to respect the rules of Stackexchange? If not, perhaps you should start your own board.